# How to get length of String[] array in a HashMap value

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm making a HashMap to store menu names as a String[] array as a value of the Map. Example:

```
Map<String, String[]> menu = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

String[] main = {"home", "news", "gallery"};
String[] user = {"profile", "messages"};
String[] admin = {"users", "stats"};
menu.put("main", main);
menu.put("user", user);
menu.put("admin", admin);
```

The main, user, and admin arrays will hold data from a database but I've put static data in for now to test it. I need to loop through each key's value array by getting the length of the value string. Example:

```
for(int i=0;i<menu.get("main").length();i++)
{
  System.out.println(menu.get("main")[i]);
}
```

The compiler complains about this line of code: menu.get("main").length() - method not found.

If I use a fixed iteration like for(int i=0;i<2;i++) it works fine.

The problem is getting the length of menu.get("main").length() properly!

**Edit**

I'm actually printing the results using JSTL in a JSP page as follows:

```
<c:set var="main_menu" value="${view.getMenu().get('main')}" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${main_menu.length}">
<c:out value="${main_menu[i]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

I'm getting an error from tomcat saying: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"

Comment: You could avoid this code entirely by using `Arrays.toString(get("main"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, of course, is the parentheses after `length`.  However, for what you're doing, the best thing would be to use an extended for loop.

```
for (String item : menu.get("main")) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

**Edit**

To do it in JSTL, you want

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${view.getMenu().get('main')}">
    <c:out value="${item}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I'm actually printing the results using JSTL in a JSP page as follows:

<c:set var="main_menu" value="${view.getMenu().get('main')}" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${main_menu.length}">
<c:out value="${main_menu[i]}" />
</c:forEach>
I'm getting an error from tomcat saying: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"

Comment: So you have a JSP/JSTL problem, but you decided to ask a parallel question for Java instead?  Why didn't you just ask the question that you wanted the answer to?  (Also, the order that posts appear varies, so "check a posts up" isn't very helpful).

Comment: Sorry my bad. I thought it would be easier to discuss it in java then I could translate the solution to JSTL. Any ideas?

Comment: Just deleted that. So any thought on how I'd fix this?

Comment: I've just seen your edit and it fixed it! Cheers for your help and sorry for messing about

Answer (score 2):

For arrays, `length` is accessed as if it were an instance variable, not a method.  Change

```
for(int i=0;i<menu.get("main").length();i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<menu.get("main").length;i++)
```

The [Java Tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) states:

> Finally, you can use the built-in length property to determine the size of any array. The following code prints the array's size to standard output:
>
> ```
> System.out.println(anArray.length);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a *field*, not a method. Also, you shouldn't call `get()` over and over, store the value somewhere:

```
String[] value = menu.get("main");

for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {  // notice it's not `length()`
    System.out.println(value[i]);
}
```

You can also use a for-each:

```
for (String a : value) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@David has already answered your question, but in case if any scenario you need to iterate with index (iteration number), you can do it as:

```
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${view.getMenu().get('main')}" varStatus="itemStatus">
        <c:out value="${itemStatus.index}" /> - <c:out value="${item}" />
    </c:forEach>
```

where "varStatus" loop tag has two fields: index and count.
    *index* starts the numbering from 0 and ends at (collection length - 1); 
    *count* starts the numbering from 1 and ends at (collection length)

The above one will print as:
1 - home
2 - news
3 - gallery

Comment: Thanks for the solution everything works now! Now I've got to get the page names from the database into the corresponding HashMap values as String[] arrays and then print them into HTML link tags